# Fill multiselect value when form are creating

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular7

I have problem with how to select value when user edit object. I have model that is loading from API. And my model шы consists of Array Peoples.

```
  id: string
  name: string
  email: string
```

I created FormGroup

```
  peoples: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
```

then fill my form value
        this.createForm.patchValue({

---

```
    peoples: this.object.peoples,
```

And im mycomponent.html i try this:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="peoples">Peoples</label>
        <select 

        multiple class="form-control" formControlName="peoples">
          <option *ngFor="let people of peopleChoose" [ngValue]="people" [selected]="peopleSelected">{{people.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

But i got all selected peoples or last.

if i add second , then selected peoples added to array peoples. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

I am idiot. Resolve it. Write function and chose her

```
[compareWith]="compareFun"
```

and need this

```
[selected]="compareFun(people, peopleSelected)"
```

all example

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="peoples">Peoples</label>
            <select [compareWith]="compareFun"
            multiple class="form-control" formControlName="peoples">
              <option *ngFor="let people of peopleChoose" [ngValue]="people" [selected]="compareFun(people, peopleSelected)">{{people.name}}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
```